# Updating Database from within a fancybox iframe form

Tags: php, mysql, fancybox

im trying to write a code where you can update the content of the database through a form inside a fancybox iframe

my code doesnt seem to work even though no errors are shown. the database is not updating

here is my code

editschool.php(this is the content of my fancybox iframe)

```
    <?php
    $temp = mysql_query("SELECT * from tertiary_school where tschool_id = $_GET[tschool_id]");
    $temp = mysql_fetch_array($temp);
    ?>
    <center>
    <form class="form-inline" method = 'post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="40%">
    Edit School Name:
    </td>
    <td>
    <input name = "tschool_name" type="text" class="input-xlarge" id = "tschool_name" value="<?php echo $temp[tschool_name]; ?>"><button type="submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="event.preventDefault(); parent.$.fancybox.close();">Save Changes</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </center>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
        {
            $tschool_name = $_POST['tschool_name'];
            $tschool_id = $_GET['tschool_id'];

            mysql_query("UPDATE tertiary_school SET tschool_name=$tschool_name WHERE tschool_id=$tschool_id") or die(mysql_error()); 
        }
    ?>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: try echoing `$tschool_name` and `$tschool_id`

Comment: i did and the correct data came out.
now my problem is why it doesnt update my database?
do i need to put some kind of parent tag in one of my code?

Comment: if everything is getting fine see my answer below

Comment: finally got it
this line prevents my code from working
onclick="event.preventDefault(); parent.$.fancybox.close();

Answer (score 0):

There is no $_GET['schoolid'] when the form posts its data..

You could update the form action attribute to be along the lines of

```
<form action="editschool.php?schoolid=<?php echo $_GET['schoolid'];?>" ...
```

Comment: my get variable came from my parent page so my get variable exists

Comment: it exists at the time of the load but not when the form is sent?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code and post output.

```
<?php
    $temp = mysql_query("SELECT * from tertiary_school where tschool_id = $_GET[tschool_id]");
    $temp = mysql_fetch_array($temp);
    ?>
    <center>
    <form class="form-inline" method = 'post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td width="40%">
    Edit School Name:
    </td>
    <td>
<input type="hidden" name="tschool_id" value="<?php echo $_GET[tschool_id];?>" />
    <input name = "tschool_name" type="text" class="input-xlarge" id = "tschool_name" value="<?php echo $temp[tschool_name]; ?>"><button type="submit" value = "submit" name = "submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="event.preventDefault(); parent.$.fancybox.close();">Save Changes</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "UPDATE `tertiary_school` SET `tschool_name`='$tschool_name' WHERE `tschool_id`='$tschool_id'";
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```